# Suppose that $\text{int}(A) \subseteq B \subseteq A$, is it true that $B \cup \text{bdy}(A) = A$?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $\text{int}(A) \subseteq B \subseteq A$, is it true that  $B \cup \text{bdy}(A) = A$?

Note: $\text{bdy}(A) $ is the boundary of $A$

Consider $A = [-1,1]$, the $\text{int}(A) = (-1,1)$, and $B = [-1,1)$, then $B \cup \text{bdy}(A) = A$.

Does this property generalize to all sets in Euclidean space?

Comment: If you change $A$ to $[-1,1)$ in your example, you'll see that $B\cup\mathop{\rm bdy}(A)$ strictly contains $A$ but also contains $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $ A^0\cup \partial A = \overline{A} $ ($ A^0 $ is the interior, $ \partial A $ is the boundary, and $ \overline{A} $ is the closure of $ A $). It is true that $ B\cup \partial A \supset A $ but not necessarily true that it equals $ A $. For instance, let $ A = (0,1) $ and let $ B=A $. Then $ B\cup \partial A = [0,1] $ which strictly contains $ A $.

We'd only have equality if $ A $ was closed (where $ A = \overline{A} $).

Comment: Beautiful. So it is true that $B \cup \text{boundary}(A)$ is always equal to the closure of $A$.

Comment: Yup, this is true since $A^0\subset B\subset A $.

Comment: @Cauchy'sCarrot No, see my example where that fails too.